# HTML attirbutes are not visible when i use :id with Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have got to add visible attirbutes to my HTML elements but they are going to invisible when it rendered.

Here is my html code:

```
<div class="created-links-wrapper" v-for="item in createdUrls" :key="item._id">
    <div class="created-link-col">
      <button v-on:click="copyToClipboard" :id="item.id">Copy</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

But its looking like that after render:

```
<button>Copy</button>
```

I want to copy text in input like this way:

```
copyToClipboard: function(e){
        var buttonId = e.target.id;
        var selectedInput = document.getElementsByName(buttonId)[0];
        selectedInput.focus();
        selectedInput.select();
        selectedInput.setSelectionRange(0, 99999);
        document.execCommand("copy");
    },
}
```

Input is dynamic so it's changing when i click "Add URL" button.

**[SOLVED]**

I changed my attribute:

```
item.id -> item._id
```

Comment: `:key="item._id"` should be `:key="item.id"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:

Button key `item.id` should be `item._id`.

Like this:

```
<button v-on:click="copyToClipboard" :id="item._id">Copy</button>
```